# On the word "thatched"

Tags: verbs, adjectives, participles

Is "thatched" the past participle of the verb "thatched" or an adjective?

The word "thatch" does have a verbal meaning and thus "thatched" as used for example in "a thatched roof" seems to be its past participle; however, "thatched" appears as headword in some dictionaries, which makes me wonder if it has come to be regarded as an adjective for itself.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/159334/42179, https://english.stackexchange.com/q/161790/42179

Comment: There are many such adjectives. _Broken, skimmed_ (as in milk), _assorted_ are a few that spring to mind.