# Turning a noun into an adjective

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, adjectives, vocabulary

In many grammar descriptions, it says that adjectives that end in -ed are used to describe a feeling (or how a person feels) or an emotion. It is used to describe a temporary thing.

With an adjective like "rented", is this a different type of adjective? Or is this just an exception to the rule?

Here are some of the grammar explanations that state this:
https://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Adjectives_ED_ING.htm

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/beginner-to-pre-intermediate/adjectives-ending-in-ed-and-ing

Comment: Hmm.  I just drove my recently washed car to the renovated restaurant to get some baked chicken and fried rice.  I had a faded photograph in the pocket of my mended shirt. … … … … … … … … Can you cite (i.e., identify by name and link) one or two of the “many grammar descriptions” that state this ‘rule’? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: So "painted", "killed", "printed", "smoked", "measured", et al are all describing temporary feelings or emotions.

Comment: In, for example, "a rented car", "rented" is a verb, not an adjective.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between an adjective and a past participle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/161790/390415) See also [verb or adjective in “The blue page is *stapled* to the red page”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/159334/390415)

Comment: @RyanM The first link is useless. It doesn't even begin to address the question of why only a few _ed_ words are adjectives.

Comment: @BillJ It explains this particular class ("rented," etc.) of *-ed* words.  Specifically, it addresses the question "With an adjective like "rented", is this a different type of adjective?"  You're right that it doesn't touch on _all_ such words, but it's far from "useless."  Perhaps it's not a 100% match, but it at least elaborates on this class of words, and it goes a bit deeper into the part-of-speech issue that you discuss in your answer.  I think it's at least relevant, even if it's not close enough for a duplicate.

Comment: @RyanM How can it address the question "With an adjective like "rented ...", when "rented" isn't even an adjective in the first place?

Comment: @BillJ The top answers to both address this exact point: ["The participle (present and past) can be _used_ as an adjective in many cases, in exactly the same way other adjectives would be used."](//english.stackexchange.com/a/161796/390415) ["The word "stapled" is either a past-participle form of a verb in a passive-voice construction... or the word could be ambiguous (where both possibilities of verb and adjective are acceptable)."](//english.stackexchange.com/a/159447/390415) The latter is less relevant to this non–passive voice example, which is why I listed it as "see also."

Comment: It doesn't give the tests for adjectivehood, which are crucial to dealing with the OP's concern that "rented" seems to be a "different type of adjective". You seem determined to confuse the OP.

Comment: In any case, you’re missing the point. The OP asked if “tested” is an exception to the "rule" that _ed_ adjectives describe a feeling (or how a person feels) or an emotion. But it isn't an 'exception' at all because it's not an adjective but a verb, as the tests prove. That’s why the tests are so important. Btw, we're talking specifically about _ed_ adjectives/verbs here, though the same would apply to the contrast between _ing_ verbs and _ing_ adjectives, e.g. "The Smiths are entertaining (_ing_ verb) the neighbours this evening" vs "The Smiths are a very entertaining (_ing_ adj) couple".

Answer (score 2):

> *a rented house*
>
> *a confused/bored child*

Your mistake is in assuming that "rented" is an adjective here. It isn't; it's a **verb**. Compare "rented" to "confused" and "bored"

[1] "Rented" can't be modified by "very", but "confused/bored" can: we can say "a very confused/bored child", but not *"a very rented car".

[2] "Rented" can't occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like "become": we can say "The child became quite bored/confused", but not *"The house became quite rented".

[3] "Rented" can't occur as complement to complex-transitive verbs like "find": we can say "I found the child quite bored/confused", but not *"I found the house quite rented".

The range of expressions that can occur as pre-head modifier to a noun is very large and varied: we don't want to call them all adjectives. "Confused" and "bored" have the properties of indisputable adjectives and hence must belong in that class, but "rented" doesn't and hence is analysed as a verb phrase in an example like "a rented car".